# Doesn't contain split method

Tags: powershell, split

Here is my code:

```
$fPath = Get-Content .\param.txt | Select-String 'adresse' -SimpleMatch
fPath = $fPath.split("=")[1]
$fPath

$paramListe = Get-Content .\param.txt | Select-String 'type' -SimpleMatch
$paramListe = $paramListe.split("=")[1]
$paramListe

$seuil = Get-Content .\param.txt | Select-String 'seuil' -SimpleMatch
$seuil = $seuil.split("=")[1]
$seuil = $seuil

$relanceAuto = Get-Content .\param.txt | Select-String 'relanceAuto' -SimpleMatch
$relanceAuto = $relanceAuto.split("=")[1]
$relanceAuto
```

And here is the imported .txt:

```
adresse=o:\******\******\DataIntegrator
type=logiciel
seuil=0
relanceAuto=yes
```

I want those variables to get the value next to the "=" sign. But everytime I launch the programm, it keeps telling me those are not strings:

> [Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.MatchInfo] does not have a method called "split".

Can someone explain to me why it doesn't work please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of the `Select-String` means that *objects* are being stored in the variables you're assigning, not strings, therefore you need to get a string value before you can use the `.split()` method.

If you do:

```
PS > $relanceAuto.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    MatchInfo                                System.Object
```

You can see that `$relanceAuto` is actually a `MatchInfo` object. You can see what properties are associated with it by:

```
PS > $relanceAuto | Format-List *


IgnoreCase : True
LineNumber : 4
Line       : relanceAuto=yes
Filename   : InputStream
Path       : InputStream
Pattern    : relanceAuto
Context    :
Matches    : {}
```

This displays that the data you actually want is contained in the `Line` property, therefore you can do the split like so:

```
PS > $relanceAuto.Line.split('=')[1]
yes
```

Comment: Great! Please remember to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when you can if it solved your problem

Comment: it's better to use `get-member ` to display properties (and methods,events etc)

Comment: @Kayasax I'm not sure I agree with "better", they do different things. For displaying properties only, FL is adequate and easier to understand for learning purposes, though gm is certainly more comprehensive

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what arco444 stated, you can also do a string conversion with your existing code by using double-quotes.

```
$relanceAuto = "$relanceAuto".Split("=")[1]
```

Comment: I was piping stuff through `Select-String` , only quoting `$_` like FormulaChris suggested allowed me to use `split` method again.